# XCode 4.5 iOS 5 simulator : The document "xxx.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed.

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I get this error in XCode 4.5 on iOS 5 simulator.

The document "xxx.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. Two members of the document have the object ID 17. This may have happened through an external edit, such as an SCM merge operation.

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can open .xib file with a text editor (such as BBEdit or TextWrangler) and change the number manually.

1. Open the XIB file in a plain text editor.
2. Search for ">17" without the quotes.
3. Replace it with a large number (don't worry, its temporary). This will eliminate the conflict.
4. Now save the file and open it in the XCode Interface builder. Xcode should notify you that there was a problem with the file and that it has repaired the problem automatically. The file should now open normally.

If for some reason the problem continues try using a different number in step 3.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply but could you elaborate ?? I tried searching for "17" but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, definitely without the quotes - I will try to make that more explicit in my future answers. Cheers!

Comment: @Fszczemton I have same problem with object ID 35. I have tried to replace it with different large numbers, but every time xcode giving me same error with different object ID. Any solution?

Comment: Maybe try the following:
1.make sure the new ID doesn't exist in the file
2. make sure the object with ID 35 is the only one duplicated (there can be other duplications as well I guess).
Hope it helps, I don't have any other idea unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue

1. Open the XIB file in a Text Editor - I used TextWrangler
2. Search for ">17" without the quotes
3. Replace it with some big number
4. Now save the file and open it in XCOde Interface builder
5. if error continue with different value then repeat the step 2 - step 4 until the xcode interface builder opens the xib file.
6. Xcode will repair the file and it will be working again.

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: I think the traditional way stack overflow works is that you accept the answer given by @Fszczemton instead of rewording it and answering again yourself :)

Comment: Oh I am sorry. Yes i understand. I thought it would be better for people to make more sense of the solution if I could put it in a sequence of steps.

Comment: That's OK :) And answering a question yourself is absolutely fine if you think it will help people who have the same problem. However, accepting @Fszczemton gives him the credit because he got there first :)

Comment: Obviously, if you rename all instances of >17 with another number (say >999), you are back where you started (i.e. duplicate object id). So, you have to judiciously rename one of the object id (assuming a two way conflict) to something else, etc.

Comment: @pradeepcg I have same problem with object ID 35. I have tried to replace it with different large numbers, but every time xcode giving me same error with different object ID. Any solution?